# How to expand partial paths in Zsh when using git commands?

Tags: zsh, git, oh-my-zsh

I use Zsh as my shell, OMZ as my package manager, and have [the git plugin](https://github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh/blob/master/plugins/git/git.plugin.zsh) in my plugins list. Whenever I type a command like `cd` or `vim` followed by a partial path, the shell expands the partial path on <kbd>TAB</kbd> press. For example, `vim ~/.v/und/` + <kbd>TAB</kbd> is expanded to `vim ~/.vim/undodir/`.

Unfortunately, I do not get such an expansion with git commands or git aliases defined in the git plugin. So if I do `git add ./nu/di/di` or `ga ./nu/di/di` and press <kbd>TAB</kbd>, the path is not expanded.

How can I instruct Zsh to perform path expansion for other commands, such as `git`?